# netsh output in a batch file skips showing my ip address

Tags: windows, netsh, ipconfig

So, I wrote a simple batch file to set a static IP and then have it reflected back to the console:

```
@echo off
netsh interface ipv4 set address "Local Area connection" static 192.168.1.100 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1
netsh interface ipv4 set dnsserver "Local Area Connection" static 8.8.8.8
netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver "Local Area Connection" 8.8.4.4
netsh interface ipv4 show config "Local Area Connection"
pause
```

However the output to the console is like this:

```
Configuration for interface "Local Area Connection"
DHCP enabled:                         No
Default Gateway:                      192.168.1.1
Gateway Metric:                       1
InterfaceMetric:                      20
Statically Configured DNS Servers:    8.8.8.8
                                      8.8.4.4
Register with which suffix:           Primary only
Statically Configured WINS Servers:   None

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Why does it not show me the IP address I statically assigned?

Comment: Does the IP get changed after running the command? Could it be getting a conflict with another machine? Also, have you tried to wait a few seconds (like 3 or 4) before issuing the show config?

Comment: Ah...I added a 3 second wait. And it now shows. Thanks! There was no other machine on the network.